# Appcelerator ACS.Users.login API Getting error code 400 with message: 'Invalid request sent.'

Tags: node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-acs

I am trying to store some data on Custom Object of Appcelerator ACS. So there will be a service to do that. Each time it require authentication to create a new object

But I am sometime getting below error while login with ACS. But it not occuring always. It only if I call service multiple time.

error i am getting is:

> {
>   success: false,
>   error: true,
>   code: 400,
>   message: "Invalid request sent."
>   }

Code used to login :

```
ACS.Users.login(userData, function(data){
    if(data.success) {
        console.log("----------Successful to login.---------------");
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
        res.end();

    } else {
        console.log("------------------login failed---------------");
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
        res.end();
    }
},req, res);
```

Can some one can help me to understand how to re-use session id from node.ACS web service app (Not web app)?

How I can keep session / check session validity before pushing something to custom object? Has anyone faced similar issue?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing in the req and res parameters into ACS.Users.login, the session is saved in the _session_id cookie:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/node_acs

When you make subsequent calls to ACS, you pass in the req and res parameters and it will check for this session token.

A session can become invalid after timeout or logout.  To check whether a session is still good, one way is to check against this REST API endpoint (GET):

https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/show/me.json?key=(YOUR ACS KEY)&_session_id=(SESSION ID OF THE USER)

Also, for some reason acs-node v0.9.3 appears to be returning the same session ID, even for different users.  Some side-effects I've seen include (1) the wrong user attempting to make a change to an object, and (2) objects created by one user are actually owned by the last person who logged in.  Making sure acs-node is at v0.9.2 avoids this issue.

Comment: thanks for your solution. Luckily issue got resolved after publishing it into cloud. It was poxy issue with our local network

Comment: Well said, node-acs 0.9.2 solved the issue I've been having with ACS returning the same session_id. thanks Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Now that **node-acs has been shut down**, everyone is obliged to move to the new **arrowdb** node sdk.

To solve the issue above about not authenticating the User, before every ArrowDB call, make sure to pass the session_id of the user like so:

```
// Connect Node.ACS to existing ACS
var ArrowDB = require('arrowdb'),
    arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('XXYYZZZ', { // ArrowDB Key
        apiEntryPoint: 'https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com',
        autoSessionManagement: false, // handle session_id yourself
        prettyJson: true,
        responseJsonDepth: 3
    }); 

// == Creates the ACS_Event for a logged in User on ArrowDB ==
function createACSEvent(uniqueId, params) {
    arrowDBApp.sessionCookieString = params.session_id; //<-- THIS IS IT!
    arrowDBApp.eventsCreate({
        name: 'someEvent',
        start_time: params.start_time,
        custom_fields: params,
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            logger.info( 'ERROR ACS_Event created '+ err);
        } else {
            logger.info( 'Success Creating ACSEvent ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
}
```